# Ban Mule ESB from blocking some requests

Tags: java, mule, esb

Some times (very frequent) mule ESB blocks some of SOAP Requests. How can i Stop Mule from doing that? i don't know what is the reason of blocking.

this is  how i have configured http-listener in mule config :

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_listener" host="${MachineName}" port="${InboundPort}"  doc:name="HTTP listener Configuration"  />      
<flow name="etryFlow" >
   <http:listener allowedMethods="POST"  config-ref="HTTP_listener" path="/{name}" doc:name="HTTP"/>

    <set-payload value="#[app.registry.pairFactory.createInputStreamWithStringKeyInstance(message.inboundProperties['http.uri.params']['name'],payload))]"  />                                  
    <jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="jms-connector" ref="UnsortedOrders" />
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="****Entry****" />                         
</flow>
```

note : the banned requests are converted into BlockingTransferInputStream instead of BufferInputStream.

thank you.

** EDIT **

this is createInputStreamWithStringKeyInstance implementation :

```
public static Pair<String, byte[]> createByteArrayWithStringKeyInstance(String key, byte value[]) throws IOException {
    return new Pair<String, byte[]>(key, value);
}
```

and Pair.java is a simple Serializable Class (same as JavaFX.Pair)
Note : The input is a SOAP XML

--EDIT -- 
 This is mule config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" 
      xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
      xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:quartz="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz"
      xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
      xmlns:jms="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms"
      xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"
      xmlns:bpm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bpm"
      xmlns:client="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/client"      
        xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" 
        xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"   
        xmlns:management="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/management"       
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd 
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.2/mule.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz/3.2/mule-quartz.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/3.2/mule-vm.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/jms/3.2/mule-jms.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/3.2/mule-scripting.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bpm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/bpm/3.2/mule-bpm.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/client http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/client/3.2/mule-client.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd                
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/management http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/management/current/mule-management.xsd ">

    <jms:activemq-connector  name="jms-connector" brokerURL="${BrokerURL}" disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true" specification="1.1"/>

    <jms:endpoint connector-ref="jms-connector" exchange-pattern="one-way" name="UnsortedOrders" queue="UnsortedOrders"/>                
    <jms:endpoint connector-ref="jms-connector" exchange-pattern="one-way" name="DestinationEMC" queue="DestinationEMC" />                
    <jms:endpoint connector-ref="jms-connector" exchange-pattern="one-way" name="DestinationOriginal" queue="DestinationOriginal"/>                           

    <management:jmx-default-config>
        <management:credentials>
          <spring:entry key="admin" value="admin"/> 
        </management:credentials>
    </management:jmx-default-config>

   <spring:beans>
        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:Application.properties"/>
        <spring:bean name="NoFactsBean" class="java.util.ArrayList" scope="singleton"/>                 
        <spring:bean id="objectStore" class="org.mule.util.store.QueuePersistenceObjectStore"/>     
        <spring:bean id ="requestBean" class="com.hamgam.hit.esb.bean.RequestBean" factory-method="getInstance" scope="singleton"/>
    </spring:beans>

    <message-properties-transformer name="contentTypeTextXML">
        <add-message-property key="Content-Type" value="text/xml;charset=UTF-8;" />
    </message-properties-transformer>        

    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_listener" host="${MachineName}" port="${InboundPort}"  doc:name="HTTP listener Configuration"  />      
    <flow name="etryFlow">
        <http:listener allowedMethods="POST" parseRequest="false"  config-ref="HTTP_listener" path="/{name}" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <object-to-byte-array-transformer/>     
        <expression-component>
            payload = app.registry.requestBean.createServiceRequest(message.inboundProperties['http.uri.params']['name'],payload);
        </expression-component>
        <jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="jms-connector" ref="UnsortedOrders"  />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="****#[payload] Enters Entry****" />
    </flow> 

    <flow name="consumeRequestsFlow" >      
        <jms:inbound-endpoint ref="UnsortedOrders" connector-ref="jms-connector" />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="**** #[payload] Enters consumeRequestsFlow ****" />     
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[app.registry.requestBean.isEMCRequired(payload)]">
                <jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="jms-connector" ref="DestinationEMC" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <jms:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="jms-connector" ref="DestinationOriginal" />
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </flow>

    <flow name="ConsumeEmcQ">
        <jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="jms-connector" ref="DestinationEMC" />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="**** #[payload] Enters ConsumeEmcQ ****" />        
        <set-payload value="#[app.registry.requestBean.sendToEMC(payload)]" />
        <until-successful objectStore-ref="objectStore" maxRetries="${MaximumRetry}" secondsBetweenRetries="${RetryInterval}">
            <http:outbound-endpoint address="${ECMURL}" exchange-pattern="one-way">             
                <transformer ref="contentTypeTextXML"/>
            </http:outbound-endpoint>
        </until-successful>  
    </flow>

    <flow name="ConsumeOrigQ">        
        <jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="jms-connector" ref="DestinationOriginal" />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="**** #[payload] Enters ConsumeOriginalQ ****" />
        <set-payload value="#[app.registry.requestBean.sendToDestination(payload)]" />         
    </flow> 

    <flow name = "EMCResponseFlow" >
        <http:inbound-endpoint host="${MachineName}" port="${EMCResponsePort}" exchange-pattern="one-way">
            <set-property propertyName="SOAPAction" value="#[message.inboundProperties['SOAPAction']]"/>
            <transformer ref="contentTypeTextXML"/>
        </http:inbound-endpoint>    
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="***EMCResponseEntry****" />
    </flow>                   
</mule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `createInputStreamWithStringKeyInstance` (which you don't describe, so it's really hard to help you) returns an `InputStream`, Mule ends up building a JMS `StreamMessage` (per [this call](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/transports/jms/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/jms/JmsMessageUtils.java#L124)).

From the Mule code, you can see it drains the streaming payload into a `StreamMessage` with this logic:

```
while ((len = value.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
    streamMessage.writeBytes(buffer, 0, len);
}
```

which is fine, provided the stream returned by `createInputStreamWithStringKeyInstance` doesn't do any fancy business behind the scene.

Also note that a JMS `StreamMessage` is probably not what you want. Did you read [its Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/StreamMessage.html)? It says:

> A StreamMessage object is used to send a stream of primitive types in the Java programming language.

I'm pretty sure you instead want to use a JMS [BytesMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html). Mule creates such a message if the payload is a `byte[]` (per the above linked transformation logic) so you'd rather have a `<object-to-byte-array-transformer/>` right before the `jms:outbound-endpoint`.

Comment: thanks. i have edited my question. i did what you told and put <object-to-byte-array-transformer/> just before <set-payload>. and that makes the original packet too loose its content-type. (service provider machine complaining : An HTTP Content-Type header is required for SOAP messaging and none was found

Comment: There's nothing in your flow that creates a proper SOAP response: what do you intend to return as the SOAP XML response? And yes, you'll need to set proper response headers, it was working "by chance" before.

Comment: Well the request is a soap message,i transform it to byte array then do some stuff with it(without changing its content) and then pass the exact request as an out bound.that is your soap xml

Comment: I did not put the whole file in here because i thought it is not necessary. Guess i was wrong

Comment: I understand that you transform the inbound SOAP request before dispatching it over JMS. What I do not understand is what SOAP response you intend to return to the client that sent the initial request over HTTP. Where is SOAP response built?

Comment: The requests meant to be one way.requester makes a request destination server answers but this conversation is not synchronized And mule is playing the man in the middles role. But i guess there is some kind of auto response enabled because the sender sees the error message that is actually created by destination server, and i am not doing it!

Comment: Mule always respond to HTTP requests, the simplest response being `200 OK` with no response entity. In that case, the response is not a valid SOAP response. You don't specify the exchange pattern on the `jms:outbound-endpoint` so it's possible that Mule uses it in `request-response` mode, thus waiting for a remote response and then routing it back to the HTTP client. You need to better control what you're actually responding over HTTP, don't just let "something happen" like that.